# WIll the system directories in different languages have the same path as the default system ones?

Tags: windows, ansi, regional-settings

I'm trying to reach a japanese path. Something like "C:\日本語\asd.dll", but I have some problems. If I force my installer to put the dll file to C:\Windows\System32, will that path be the same in all language versions of Windows or it will be in the regional language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot in general rely on paths being the same. Always use the environment variables - you can guarantee that the environment variable names will *not* be localized (i.e. "%SystemRoot%" works *everywhere*). In your example, you would want to put the file in `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

Though, I would advise to not be putting DLLs in this directory, as it belongs to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The path depends on the language that the user set up Windows with. Things like WINDIR should be usable regardless.

Answer (score 0):

what install system are you using? NSIS has a variable that holds the path to the Windows system directory: $SYSDIR

Answer (score 0):

I installed Windows 8 French and Windows 8 Russian from DVD iso's from MSDN. In the Explorer window the system paths were shown in French or Russian, but in the command prompt the system paths were in English (ex. C:/Program Files/)